# Use Variable As Dictionary Key Set

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I parse a JSON file to a dictionary, example JSON data below

```
 {
    "environmental": {
      "temprature": {
           "test" : "temprature",
           "unit": "c", 

           "now": 12.65,
           "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18", 

           "min": "12.5", 
           "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02", 

           "max": "32.84", 
           "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03"
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to either retrieve a value or set a value using a list tuple or string as the dictionary key.

```
var_lst_key = ["environmental", "temprature", "now"]
var_dict_x[var_lst_key] = "x"
```

or

```
print(var_dict_x[var_lst_key])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you expect should happen when you do `var_dict_x[var_lst_key] = "x"` or `print(var_dict_x[var_lst_key])`

Comment: "list tuple or string" is supposed to be "list, tuple or string", right?

Comment: There's definitely an existing question about this (using a list to do a nested dict lookup), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1: Doing it the easy way: using functions

A nested lookup is pretty easy to do. You iterate over the keys, and keep replacing the object you're looking into with the value at the key you're currently looking at:

```
def nested_get(obj, keys):
    for key in keys:
        obj = obj[key]
    return obj

def nested_set(obj, keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        # Drill down until the penultimate key
        obj = obj[key]
    # Set value of last key
    obj[keys[-1]] = value
```

To run this:

```
jstr = """{ "environmental": {
      "temprature": {
           "test" : "temprature",
           "unit": "c", 

           "now": 12.65,
           "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18", 

           "min": "12.5", 
           "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02", 

           "max": "32.84", 
           "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03"
      }
}}"""

jobj = json.loads(jstr)

var_lst_key = ["environmental", "temprature", "now"]
nested_lookup(jobj, var_lst_key) # Returns 12.65

invalid_keys = ["environmental", "temprature", "hello"] 
nested_lookup(jobj, invalid_keys) # throws KeyError 'hello'

nested_set(jobj, var_lst_key, "HELLO!")
nested_lookup(jobj, var_lst_key) # Returns HELLO!
```

### Part 2: Doing it the fancy way: using a derived class

Now if you *really* want to use the `dict[key] = value` syntax, you're going to have to extend the `dict` class to override its `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` methods.

```
class NestedLookupDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.insert_missing_keys = True


    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        # Get the super dictionary for easy lookup
        obj = self
        for i in indices:
            obj = dict.__getitem__(obj, i)
        return obj
    
    def __setitem__(self, indices, value):
        # Get the base dictionary
        obj = self
        # Drill down until the penultimate key
        for i in indices[:-1]:
            # Insert a new dict if a key is missing
            if self.insert_missing_keys and not dict.__contains__(obj, i):
                dict.__setitem__(obj, i, dict())
            obj = dict.__getitem__(obj, i)
        # Set the value at the final key
        dict.__setitem__(obj, indices[-1], value)
```

To use this, let's use the json object parsed from the string like before:

```
# jobj = {... something ...}
nested_dict = NestedLookupDict(jobj)

print(nested_dict[var_lst_key]) # Prints 12.65

nested_dict[var_lst_key] = "HELLO!"

print(nested_dict[var_lst_key]) # Prints HELLO!
```

When `nested_dict.insert_missing_keys` is set to `True` (by default), the `__setitem__()` method adds missing dictionaries if required.

```
newkey = ["environmental", "temprature", "newkey"]
nested_dict[newkey] = "NEWKEY!!!"
print(nested_dict[newkey]) # Prints NEWKEY!!!

newkey2 = ["environmental", "temprature", "nested", "newkey"]
nested_dict[newkey2] = "NESTEDNEWKEY!!!"
print(nested_dict[newkey2]) # Prints NESTEDNEWKEY!!!
```

At the end of all this, you can dump the object to json to see what it looks like:

```
print(json.dumps(nested_dict))

# Output: 
{
    "environmental": {
        "temprature": {
            "test": "temprature",
            "unit": "c",
            "now": "HELLO!",
            "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18",
            "min": "12.5",
            "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02",
            "max": "32.84",
            "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03",
            "newkey": "NEWKEY!!!",
            "nested": {
                "newkey": "NESTEDNEWKEY!!!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Part 3: Way overkill, but oh! so much fun to code: Souped up NestedLookupDict

Additional features to so you can use it almost like `dict`:

- Delete keys using `del nested_dict[key]`
- Check if keys exist with `key in nested_dict`
- `nested_dict.get(key, default)` absorbs the `KeyError` if `key` doesn't exist, and returns `default`
- Implemented a type check on `keys`: they must be `list` or `tuple` now

Quirks:

- Because of the way `__getitem__()` is implemented, `nested_dict[empty_list]` returns a reference to `nested_dict` (itself). If this is a bad thing, a check for empty keys could be added. However, I don't see any problems coming from leaving it this way. Some consequences of this quirk:

  - To keep this behavior consistent with how `__contains__()` works, the `__contains__()` function returns `True` for empty `key`. `[] in nested_list := True`
  - You cannot, by definition, set `nested_list[[]]`. That throws a ValueError

```
class NestedLookupDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.insert_missing_keys = True

    def check_keys(self, keys):
        if not isinstance(keys, (list, tuple)):
            raise TypeError("keys must be of type list or tuple")

    def get(self, keys, default=None):
        self.check_keys(keys)
        try:
            return self.__getitem__(keys)
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __contains__(self, keys):
        self.check_keys(keys)
        if not keys: return True # nested_dict contains the key [] = itself
        if len(keys) > 1:
            return self.__getitem__(keys[:-1]).__contains__(keys[-1])
        else:
            return dict.__contains__(self, keys[0])

    def __delitem__(self, keys):
        self.check_keys(keys)
        obj = self
        for i in keys[:-1]:
            obj = dict.__getitem__(obj, i)
        dict.__delitem__(obj, keys[-1])

    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        self.check_keys(keys)
        # Get the super dictionary for easy lookup
        obj = self
        for i in keys:
            obj = dict.__getitem__(obj, i)
        return obj
    
    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        self.check_keys(keys)
        if not keys: raise ValueError("keys cannot be empty")
        # Get the base dictionary
        obj = self
        # Drill down until the penultimate key
        for i in keys[:-1]:
            # Insert a new dict if a key is missing
            if self.insert_missing_keys and not dict.__contains__(obj, i):
                dict.__setitem__(obj, i, dict())
            obj = dict.__getitem__(obj, i)
        # Set the value at the final key
        dict.__setitem__(obj, keys[-1], value)
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing thank you so so much, I really do appreciate it exactly what I wanted!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the json and load it as dict as follows:

```
# importing the module
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
  
    # Print the type of data variable
    print("Type:", type(data))
  
    # Print the data of dictionary
    print("\nPeople1:", data['people1'])
    print("\nPeople2:", data['people2'])
```

The following code outputs each element from dictionary using keys

Comment: Thanks venkatesh I can load the data to a dict however how ever my question was.

Comment: I would like to either retrieve a value or set a value using a list tuple or string as the dictionary key.

var_lst_key = {"environmental", "temprature", "now"}
var_dict_x[var_lst_key] = "x"
or

print(var_dict_x[var_lst_key])

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP's asking how to use a tuple to do a nested lookup.