# Python how to access specific json dictionary value by chaining the 'key'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

If I have the following Json:

```
{
"a": {
       "b" : {
               "c" : "value"
             }
      }
}
```

This is loaded into my object (obj) via json.load()

Then I have another variable which is

```
path = "a.b.c"
```

To access the value of 'c' in the json, I would typically do:

```
obj["a"]["b"]["c"]
```

However I would like to leverage the 'path' variable, and do something like this:

```
obj[path]
```

Is this possible? How can this be achieved

Comment: it's the json path to the value of 'c' (in the provided json, '.' delimits a new object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Variable As Dictionary Key Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182453/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-set)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the path on dot and use `reduce` to get the nested value.

```py
from functools import reduce
d = {'a':{'b':{'c':'value'}}}
path = "a.b.c"
val = reduce(lambda o, k: o[k], path.split("."), d)
print(val)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qTlNoK)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that takes both the JSON data and the path as arguments. It can iterate through each key in the path (separated by `.`) and traverse through the JSON that way.

```
def json_from_path(data: dict, path: str):
    for key in path.split('.'):
        data = data[key]
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do so using a combination of [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) and [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> dct = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'value'}}}
>>> reduce(getitem, "a.b.c".split("."), dct)
'value'
```

The way this works is that reduce will initially invoke `getitem` using `dct` and the first item from the `"a.b.c".split()` i.e `"a"` and then the result of it is then passed to `getitem` in next iteration but this time with `"b"` and so on...

```
>>> getitem(dct, "a")
{'b': {'c': 'value'}}
>>> getitem(getitem(dct, "a"), "b")
{'c': 'value'}
>>> getitem(getitem(getitem(dct, "a"), "b"), "c")
'value'
```

And `getitem` in itself works like:

```
>>> getitem?
Signature: getitem(a, b, /)
Docstring: Same as a[b].
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a third-party installation, but the [`jq` package](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) lets you traverse data structures using the `jq` filter language.

```
>>> import jq
>>> d = {"a": {"b": {"c": "value"}}}
>>> jq.compile(".a.b.c").input(d).first()
'value'
```

(Note that `.` has to precede each key, rather than simply separating the keys, in the path.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little beyond the scope of the question, but you can always subclass the `dict` type and overwrite the `__getitem__`  method to get the result you are looking for.

This is the way that you could actually achieve the result the OP is asking for with the syntax used by the OP.

For example:

```
class Dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, val):
        try: return super().__getitem__(val)
        except KeyError:
            keys = val.split(".")
            value = super().__getitem__(keys[0])
            d = Dict(value)
            return d['.'.join(keys[1:])]
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
path = 'a.b.c'
obj = Dict({"a": {"b" : {"c" : "value"}}})

result = obj[path]

print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
value
```